# Did any Middle Eastern country adopt the SDFI system or similar?

Tags: middle-east, oil, norway

> In the early days, foreign companies dominated exploration activities,
> and they were responsible for developing the first oil and gas fields.
> Norwegian participation gradually increased as Norsk Hydro became
> involved. Saga Petroleum, a private Norwegian company, was established
> in 1972. Statoil (now Equinor) was also established in 1972, with the
> Norwegian state as sole owner. Norway also established the principle
> that the state was to have a 50 per cent ownership interest in every
> production licence.
>
> From 1 January 1985, this system was reorganised. The Norwegian
> state’s participating interest was split in two: one part linked to
> Statoil and one to the State’s Direct Financial Interest (SDFI) in the
> petroleum industry.
>
> The SDFI system means that the Norwegian state owns holdings in a
> number of oil and gas fields, pipelines and onshore facilities. The
> proportion is determined when production licences are awarded, and
> varies from field to field. As one of several owners, the State covers
> its share of investments and costs, and receives a corresponding share
> of the income from production licences. Statoil was made responsible
> for handling the commercial aspects of SDFI on behalf of the state.

https://www.norskpetroleum.no/en/framework/norways-petroleum-history/

Norway decided to own 50 percent of every production licence when it came to oil production, but then it shifted to a more complex system called the SDFI system where Norway owns holdings in a number of oil and gas fields, pipelines and onshore facilities. I was wondering if any Middle Eastern country decided to adopt a similar system when it comes to oil production.

Comment: Do a system where the monarch personally owns all or substantially all of the oil and gas wealth count?